# vb.net Dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I have added a reference (component) into a project. I need to create a control array using dictionary and I want to add the item as that reference component. How to add the item as that component and call the constuctor of dictionary .I have code like

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Add(0, New WImage)
End Sub


Public Sub Add(ByVal new_key As Integer, ByVal new_AxWImageArray As WImage) 
    Dictionary.Add(new_key, new_AxWImageArray)
End Sub


Default Public Property Item(ByVal key As Integer) As WImage
    Get

        Return DirectCast(Dictionary.Item(key), WImage)

        ' Return CType(_mydictionary.IndexOf(key, Values), WImage)

    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As WImage)
        Dictionary.Item(key) = Value
    End Set

End Property
```

I get Object reference error at    `Me.Add(0, New WImage)`
of `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Where is `Dictionary` declared and initialized?